# Play - BodyParser can't parse request without Content-Type

Tags: playframework, http-headers

For some reason, some POST/PUT requests from IE 8 don't have Content-Type in their headers, which make **BodyParser** can not parse the request properly, causing Play can not get parameter in the form.

To solve that, I was thinking overriding **onRequest** in the **Global**. But sadly I can not modify request in the method(except **username**).

I pretty much want to solve this issue just in Global instead of controllers.

Is there a way out of this?

Thx!!!

Comment: Is this for Play Java or Scala?